# find the difference of the dates?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, linked-list, skip-lists

I have bunch of events are scheduled, and I want to check if there is a 10day interval in my scheduled events where within that 10 day there is no event is taking place. Is there good data structure and search algo to find 10 day interval ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you care about efficiency, memory usage, etc. If all else fails, you can sort by date using an O(n*log(n)) algorithm and take the difference between each consecutive pair of dates.

EDIT: Think I understand your problem better now.
Two options:
1) Assuming the dates are sorted, binary search them stopping when the increment between two of them is <10. Perhaps you could search the subarrays with larger date ranges preferentially. This falls somewhere between log n and n.
2) Store difference from prev or next date with the dates. Use a priority queue to keep them sorted by difference from prev or next date. You can pop the date with max difference in constant time.

Comment: I need logn runtime efficiency, not space

Comment: Yes, that was a fairly obvious and non-optimal suggestion in retrospect. Do you expect this task to be common? There are definitely some wasteful ways to keep track of intervals between all the dates allowing you to essentially find out if/where a 10-day interval exists in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ordered linked-list to store the events and also I would store the events in a hash table (key: event date), which are at least 10 days earlier than the next one. When you insert a new event to the linked list you have to check the date difference between the new event and its neighbours. Up to that modify the hash table.

**EDIT:**

Maybe there is no need for creating an extra hashtable. Create a special ordered linked-list, where the list-item looks like that:

[eventDate|nextEventPointer|next10DayEventPointer|previous10DayEventPointer]

next10DayEventPointer points to the next event, which at least 10 days earlier than the next one.
previous10DayEventPointer points to the previous event, which at least 10 days earlier than the next one.

The HEAD item next10DayEventPointer points to the first event which at least earlier than the next one. The HEAD item previous10DayEventPointer is NULL.

You can query the 10Day events start at HEAD using next10DayEventPointer.

During the insertion you have to update the pointers if neccessary.

**EDIT:**

Use binary search like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> result = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        int [] dates = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7,18, 19, 23, 33, 34, 35, 50, 70};

        IsThereIntervalXBetween(dates, 10, 0, dates.Length - 1, result);
        foreach (var key in result.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine("Index:{0} Date:{1} Next:{2}",key,dates[key],dates[key+1]);
    }

    static void IsThereIntervalXBetween(int[] dates, int interval, int firstIndex, int lastIndex, Dictionary<int, int> result)
    {
        if (lastIndex - firstIndex == 1)
        {
            result.Add(firstIndex, dates[firstIndex]);
            return;
        }

        int middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;

        if (dates[middleIndex] - dates[firstIndex] >= interval)
            IsThereIntervalXBetween(dates, interval, firstIndex, middleIndex, result);


        if (dates[lastIndex] - dates[middleIndex] >= interval)
            IsThereIntervalXBetween(dates, interval, middleIndex, lastIndex, result);
    }
}
```

This is recursive, which is not preferable, but still it's easy to transform to non-recursive.

Comment: ok, when I insert events in the hashtable, if there are two event within 10 days I cannot insert a event, how would I find the next available 10day empty slot to insert an event in logn ? you algo seems O(n)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, I have events scheduled. let's assume these are event dates, 3 5 8 10 12 14 15 19 23 33 34 39 40 45 and you see there is a interval (23-33) of 10 days. I want to find that interval in logn

Comment: In this case you could use binary search trees. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree Every node has two child, the child at left is less than the parent node, the child at right is bigger than the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

u can have sorted linked-list to store schedule and also store same in a hash map with date as key and value as address of linked-list node-address. So to search and see whether u have 10 days time for a schedule its o(1) time and to insert a schedule its max o(n) time.